# Kafka cluster configuration check

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

`Kafka` comes with various `.sh script` to perform management activities on `Kafka` cluster such as topic creation, partition etc. But I am after `.sh script` which would allow me to inspect (discover) the active (in-force) configuration of building blocks such as broker, topic, partitions etc.

Is there any `.sh script` that is available which does this configuration inspection at runtime ?

Note: I would like to view all configuration key/value entries (including default and overridden if any) for broker/topic/partition together or ideally separate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `topics.sh` and describe the topic to get config detail related to the `topic`, `the number of partition`, `replication factor`,  `in sync replicas`.
Try

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic
```

You will get something like:

```
Topic:my-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: my-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,2,0
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to see all configuration key/value entries (including default and overridden if any) for broker/topic/partition together or ideally separate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you are probably after something like the following

`kafka-configs.sh $ZK --describe --entity-type topics`
This will provide the config for all topics. If no values exist for a topic then it means they are using the defaults (usually in `server.properties`).

Instead of `topics` you can also use `brokers`, `clients` and `users`.

Comment: Thanks. This is only showing overridden values and not consolidated configuration entries. I would prefer both together for inspection. I don't mind writing some .sh script if possible.

Comment: I think you might have to. The out of the box kafka scripts are pretty basic. If you plan on writing a script to do it it might be easier to work with json output provided by [kt](https://github.com/fgeller/kt). It might not provide configs such as those in `server.properties` but it might be easier to merge them with the output of kt. It will just require some shell magic probably.